Display Last Week data that is up to the current date/time of the current week
I am trying to finalize my query that I am trying to do comparisons of data from This Week vs Last Week. What I need to limit last weeks data that has the same number of days and is up to the same hour of the current date.
Example:
Current Date is: Tuesday (Day 3), 10:00a, in Week 50.
Results I need is:
LAST WEEK (Week 49) includes: All of Sunday, All of Monday, and Tuesday up to 10:00a.
This Code gets Last Week's data, but includes ALL of Tuesday:
WHERE 
  /* Current Year*/ 
  YEAR(DATE_FIELD) = YEAR(GETDATE()) AND
  
  /* LAST WEEK*/
  DATEPART(week, DATE_FIELD) = DATEPART(week, GETDATE()) - 1 AND

  /*Same Days last week to current week*/
  ( DATEPART(dw,DATEADD(day,0,DATE_FIELD)) <= DATEPART(dw,DATEADD(day,0,GETDATE())) )


I think this is what I need to include somehow, but if I add it in I only get the results that up to 10:00 on Sun, Mon, Tue..,
/* AND DATEPART(HH,DATE_FIELD) <= DATEPART(HH,GETDATE()) */

How can I get Last Weeks data that includes ALL Sun, ALL Mon, and Tues up to 10:00 (current weeks time)

Please provide example data and expected results

What version of SQL-Server are you using?

This can get... odd around the end of the year if you use week numbers instead of just 7 day spans. How do you want that handled? Also, what version of SQL Server, because the latest has some new functions that might help with this.

@BartMcEndree
MSSQL 2019
Results i'm looking for is hard to explain, but for instance:
Currently Today is Tuesday 2:00p (Day 3, Week 50, 14H).
I want Last Weeks Data (Days 1 - 3, Week 59) but include only Tuesday's data up to the 'current hour' at 2:00p (14H).  I don't want to see last weeks data that is say Tuesday at 3:00, until its 3:00 currently.

@JoelCoehoorn I didn't plan on end of the year situation.  I'm pretty new to SQL, but its really only 1 week then that gets mis-aligned i'm OK with that as long as the other weeks get the right comparisons

@BartMcEndree, if i wanted to do a monthly comparison Example Today is 12/11 10:30a (last month 11/1 - 11/11 up to 10:30a)..  I was trying to change some configurations, but couldn't quite get to the same day hour, just all of last month.
Would you happen to know how to do that by Month or Year as well?

This is the WHERE clause you could use:
WHERE 
  /* Current Year*/ 
  YEAR(DATE_FIELD) = YEAR(GETDATE()) 
  
  /* LAST WEEK*/
  AND DATEPART(week, DATE_FIELD) = DATEPART(week, GETDATE()) - 1 

  /*Same Days last week to current week*/
  AND ( DATEPART(dw,DATEADD(day,0,DATE_FIELD)) <= DATEPART(dw,DATEADD(day,0,GETDATE())) )    

  AND 
    (
      --Same day last week only includes hours up to now
      (DATEADD(day, -7, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE())) = DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, DATE_FIELD)) AND DATEPART(HH,DATE_FIELD) <= DATEPART(HH,GETDATE()))
      OR
      --otherwise include all hours of the day
      DATEADD(day, -7, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE())) != DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, DATE_FIELD)) 
    )

UK Fiddle  Please note that this fiddle is hosted in the UK which is +5 hours compared to Eastern Time (ET)

Bart, That is the perfect!  Thank you so much!

Pretty sure you could combine the line /*Same Days last week to current week*/ into your new logic.

How would I be able to do something similar instead of weekly, but Monthly or Yearly comparisons to the same time last month/year to current month/year?

@jsg5120 change DATEPART(dw to DATEPART(m. Also DATEADD(day, -7  to DATEADD(month, -1

where date_field<=dateadd(week,-1,@CurDate)
and datepart(week,date_field)=datepart(week,dateadd(week,-1,@CurDate))

i dont know what value  date_field hold.
